# Need to add one by one value to comma separated List from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to add one bye one value to comma separated list

my code

```
var Plist, Llist;
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var id = results[i].id;
    if (id.startsWith("P")) {
        Plist = // Add comma separated value
    } else if (id.startsWith("L")) {
        Llist = // add comma repeated value
    }
}
```

please suggest better solution...

Comment: Better solution than what? Your code is not even trying.

Comment: Do you know the answer??. Do you have any solution?

Comment: It's pretty clear what he wants, he has an array and wants to split it into two comma separated string lists.

Comment: That's not my point, the point is SO is mostly for issues with code, it's not for asking people to come up with the code you need.

Comment: I just asked .What is best solution for this issue. Otherwise i am not going break your point. make sense?

Comment: If you know the answer you can come and say.otherwise your just trying to over smart in this forum

Comment: keep on your mind!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: [StackOverflow isn't a forum](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), it's a FAQ, and that's where you miss the point. Beware of your tone, by the way.

Comment: Why you putting hands on my reputation?. I think this question is clear??

Comment: i think i asked meaningful question with clearly >is it right?

Answer (score 3):

```
var Plist = "", Llist = "";
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var id = results[i].id;
    if (id.startsWith("P")) {
        Plist += id + ",";
    } else if (id.startsWith("L")) {
        Llist += id + ",";
    }
}

if (Plist.indexOf(',') !== -1) {
    Plist = Plist.substring(0, Plist.length - 1);
}

if (Llist.indexOf(',') !== -1) {
    Llist = Llist.substring(0, Llist.length - 1);
}
```

Comment: `PList` and `Llist` are undefined and you're appending strings to it?

Comment: You are right, I just wrote the code and was reviewing it. You got to figure out that just few seconds prior to me :)

Comment: Thanks for your great support!!!!!